# Inserting Next.js Links into an html string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, next.js

I have an html string that I retrieve from an API.

```
const htmlString = "<p>Hello World</p>";
```

I'm using react's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to display that content on my page.

Now before displaying it, I'd like to process it and put a link on "**World**". But not an `<a>` Tag. I need an actual Next.js `<Link>` tag. So a string replace probably won't do the job.

The result I want to achieve in jsx is:

```
const processed = <p>Hello <Link href="/my-route"><a>World</a></Link></p>
```

I've thought of using React.createElement but I'm not sure how to interpolate the content inside the string.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I came across this and found it to be an interesting problem.

Assuming the string from the API is always going to be `"<p>Hello World</p>"` you could do something like this:

```js
const string = '<p>Hello World</p>';
    
const processed = string.replace(/\bWorld\b/, `<Link href="/my-route">$&</Link>`);
    
console.log(processed);
```

We are using the `.replace` method with a regular expression to replace "World" with itself surrounded by `<Link>` tags. The `.replace` allows us to specify the string as a replacement by writing `$&` within the second argument.

.replace documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score -1):

```html
Hello<Link href="https://github.com">World</Link>
```

You dont need to specify another anchor tag inside a link. This should work fine.